# How to access List elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
list = [['vegas','London'],['US','UK']]
```

How to access each element of this list?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question, one that leads me to believe you urgently need to read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). For example, it seems your data structure does not make much sense, a dictionary might be a better choice: `cities = {"Vegas": "US", "London": "UK"}`.

Comment: Also, you are overriding the default `list`. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and try not to redefine the default data-structures (`list`, `set`, `dict`, `tuple`) or anything in the global `dir()` that does not belong to you.

Answer (score 41):

I'd start by not calling it `list`, since that's the name of the constructor for Python's built in `list` type.

But once you've renamed it to `cities` or something, you'd do:

```
print(cities[0][0], cities[1][0])
print(cities[0][1], cities[1][1])
```

Answer (score 9):

It's simple

```
y = [['vegas','London'],['US','UK']]

for x in y:
    for a in x:
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried `list[:][0]` to show all first member for each list inside list is not working. Result will be the same as `list[0][:]`.

So i use list comprehension like this:

```py
print([i[0] for i in list])
```

which return first element value for each list inside list.

PS: I use variable `list` as it is the name used in the question. I will not use this as a variable name since it is the basic function `list()` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Learn python the hard way ex 34

try this

```
animals = ['bear' , 'python' , 'peacock', 'kangaroo' , 'whale' , 'platypus']

# print "The first (1st) animal is at 0 and is a bear." 

for i in range(len(animals)):
    print "The %d animal is at %d and is a %s" % (i+1 ,i, animals[i])

# "The animal at 0 is the 1st animal and is a bear."

for i in range(len(animals)):
    print "The animal at %d is the %d and is a %s " % (i, i+1, animals[i])
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question with the nested lists.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution to print all items in a list:

```
def printItems(l):
   for i in l:
      if isinstance(i,list):
         printItems(i)
      else:
         print i


l = [['vegas','London'],['US','UK']]
printItems(l)
```