# Python: How to get the nth element from list, where n is from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

So say I have:

```
a = ['the dog', 'cat', 'the frog went', '3452', 'empty', 'animal']
b = [0, 2, 4]
```

How can I return:

```
c = ['the dog', 'the frog went', 'empty'] ?
```

i.e how can I return the nth element from a, where n is contained in a separate list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access List elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613131/how-to-access-list-elements)

Comment: @d_kennetz not at all a duplicate of that, even though I agree that from the title it could look like so.

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino the premise is the same. accessing items in a list by their index (just because indexes are in another list) doesn't really change much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehension, just do:

```
c = [a[x] for x in b]
```

Answer (score 2):

An other way is :

```
map(a.__getitem__, b)
```

Comment: Good use of map. could also cast to list which will work in both python2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution: if you are willing to use numpy (`import numpy as np`), you could use its fancy indexing feature (à la Matlab), that is, in one line:

```
c = list(np.array(a)[b])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, list comprehension iterating over `a` instead (less efficient):

```
[ e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i in b ]

#=> ['the dog', 'the frog went', 'empty']
```

O with `lambda`:

```
map( lambda x: a[x], b )
```